# Capybara-webkit: disable iframe load during tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, iframe, capybara, capybara-webkit

I'm testing a page that have various embedded youtube videos. Capybara-webkit is extremely slow to load and test that page, so I need to disable iframes load for that page.

The iframe looks like that:

```
<iframe class="embedly-embed" src="//cdn.embedly.com/widgets/media.html?src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fembed%2FKxu2A7-uBus%3Ffeature%3Doembed&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DKxu2A7-uBus&amp;image=http%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FKxu2A7-uBus%2Fhqdefault.jpg&amp;key=7c4c130437b3403ab254d76c5015b5a5&amp;type=text%2Fhtml&amp;schema=youtube" width="854" height="480" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

I tried two approaches:

**Blacklisting the url:**

```
Capybara.register_driver :webkit do |app|
  # Disabling useless resources loading from capybara
  driver = Capybara::Webkit::Driver.new(app)
  driver.browser.url_blacklist = [
    '//cdn.embedly.com/*',
    '//cdn.embedly.com/widgets/*',
    'http://cdn.embedly.com/widgets/*'
  ]
  driver
end
```

**Set all iframes as `display: none;`**

(In application.html.erb)

```
<% if Rails.env.test? %>
  <style>iframe {display:none}</style>
<% end %>
```

Both of them failed...

Any ideas?

Comment: What about blacklisting youtube instead of embedly?

Comment: @MichalSzyndel I tried `https://www.youtube.com/*`, no change :\

Comment: It seems like blacklisting is not working at all...

Comment: Maybe it's just taking another format? Strangely your question seems to be about only resource on that topic.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel I used this as an example: https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/blob/master/spec/driver_spec.rb#L2544

Comment: Ok, what if you tried blocking your own asset path for example? Does this work?

Comment: @MichalSzyndel I just tried those: `["http://#{Capybara.server_host}/assets/*"]` and `['*']`. No effect at all. :|

Comment: And also: `"http://#{Capybara.server_host}:#{Capybara.server_port}/assets/*"` and all possible variants.

Comment: Ok, are you sure you run compatible versions of gem and capybara? Can't think of any other possible reasons.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel ... you're right! I was using capybara-webkit 1.2, so it have no wildcard! *facepalm*
In fact it seems to work now
Sorry for your time...

Comment: Don't worry, glad your problem is solved!